# Django equivalent for MySQL's FIND_IN_SET()

Tags: mysql, django

In a legacy MySQL database I have a table with a field that is a comma-separated list of values:

```
id  | field
---------------
1   | 2,4,8
2   | 1,4,15,24
```

What is the Django equivalent of the following query?

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(15, field)
```

Assume Django sees this field as a regular `CharField`.

Comment: A module would not be of any help. Sure I can do the query (by using custom SQL like Daniel suggested), I was wondering whether there's a Django ORM equivalent.

Comment: Yeah! I was about to tell you to use raw SQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For stuff that's that custom i think you may be stuck with [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)

Example:

```
# Warning, MySQL specific query ahead!
Model.objects.extra(where=['FIND_IN_SET(15, field)'])
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't one. And there shouldn't be one. This is a particularly non-standard MySQL function, and Django is not concerned with db-specific behaviour. Use custom SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Use the extra() method as a last resort. As per the Django documentation extra() method can be deprecated at any point.

It's better to use regex in Django.

**Example:**

- Model.objects.filter(field__iregex = r'(24),?')

The above QuerySet will check for digit '24' in field column and also matches either if the comma is followed by the digit (24,25) or if only digit (12,24).